# using powershell to append to an existing system variable

Tags: string, powershell, string-comparison, string-concatenation

Morning everyone,
This is a question specific to product licensing.
We have many servers hosting licenses for engineering software that share the same variable name but on different servers.
So if for instance I have an existing system variable let's say
"
$LM_LICENSE_FILE="server1,server2,server3"  and $LM_LICENEFILE_NEW = "server4,server5,server6"

I want to append to it only if the new license variable is "different" separated by a semicolon.
So if $LM_LICENSE_FILE=$LM_LICENSE _FILE_NEW
Do nothing
Else LM_LICENSE_FILE= $(LM_LICENSE_FILE) + ";" +(LM_LICENSE_FILE_NEW)

The value I want would be LM_LICENSE_File=server1,server2,server3;server4,servr5,server6

What would be the method to compare and append this path in powershell?
Thanks,
Carl G.

Researching this and I know very little about powershell outside of searching for what want and modifying.
I would assume this would be a string compare and a concatenate if the strings don't match.
Just don't know enough about powershell to tell people what I want.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Could make a minimal effort at solving the problem, only thing you need for this is an `if` condition checking for inequality `-ne`

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
$LM_LICENSE_FILE="server1,server2,server3"
$licnesesSplit = $LM_LICENSE_FILE.Split(',')
$LM_LICENEFILE_NEW = "server1, server4,server5,server6"
$licnesesSplitnew = $LM_LICENEFILE_NEW.Split(',')
foreach($license in $licnesesSplitnew)
{
   if(-not $licnesesSplit.Contains($license))
   {
      $LM_LICENSE_FILE += ("," + $license)
   }
}
$LM_LICENSE_FILE
```